# jQuery accordion fails in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, accordion

I am using JSON, Ajax and jQuery in my application. In my html I have the following tag:

```
<div id="tab"></div>
```

The Ajax script is as follows (simplified, with only necessary code shown ):

```
function checkVal() {
    if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(AJAX.responseText);
        var item = json.Item;
        txt = "<div#tab>";

        for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            txt = txt + "<h3>" + item[i].ItemId + "</h3>";
            txt = txt + "<p>" + item[i].ItemName;
            txt = txt + "<br>" + item[i].Price + "</p>";
        }
        jQuery('div#tab').html(txt + "</div>");
    }
}
```

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
jQuery('div#tab').accordion({collapsible:true});
```

I found that the accordion is not working, even though data is properly displayed. I also found that `jQuery('div#tab').draggable()` works though accordion fails.

Can someone explain this strange behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i think your for loop has problem as far as you've posted, shouldnt it be like:

```
var txt = "";
for(i=0;i<item.length;i++) {
    txt+="<h3>"+item[i].ItemId+"</h3>";
    txt+= "<div><p>" +item[i].ItemName;
    txt+= "<br>" +item[i].Price+ "</p></div>";
}
jQuery('div#tab').html(txt);
```

Comment: If you mean having the <p> within <div> I have tried that too...but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes Sudhir, I had edited my question so that the div tag was outside the loop.

Comment: I am finding something even more strange. If I remove the for loop and I directly write `jQuery("div#tab").html("<h3>Test1</h3><p>One</p><h3>Test2</h3><p>Two</p>");` inside the checkVal() function, even then the accordion is not working. But I write the same code as part of the jQuery script, it works fine. Any idea on how what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

with `jQuery('div#tab').html(txt);` in the loop, you overwrite the div every time. you should do it after the loop

According to your edit:

```
txt=""
    for{...}
$('#tab').html(txt)
```

so remove the "div"-tag from the txt, when  already exists in html-code

Comment: I have tried that as well. Also, it is as if none of the elements generated from the function are getting recognised. If I write a alert for click on <h3> it is not working. Only the div is getting recognised, not the elements inside it.

Comment: Found something on live() function in jQuery and now I am able to access the elements inside div. But the accordion problem solution still eludes me.

Comment: you create the <h3> "on the fly", so be sure, that you add the click function after the elements inside the div already exist